# Change text size of the last character of String

Tags: java, android, string, spannablestring

I've spent some time in this, searching here and trying some different solutions with SpannableString, but I can't find the correct way to do it.

That I want to do is change the size of the last character of my string.
Example 200(size 22) $(size 15)

Code :

```
txPriceBefore.setText(getPrice() + " $")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way...

```
 String yourString= getPrice() + " $";
 SpannableString spanString=  new SpannableString(yourString);
 spanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), yourString.length()-1,yourString.length(), 0); // set size
 txPriceBefore.setText(spanString);
```

Comment: What's the 's' that you put in new SpannableString(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Call this method

```
txPriceBefore.setText(setSpanableString(getPrice() + " $"))

public SpannableString setSpanableString(String textString){

            int startIndex = textString.indexOf("₹$");

            SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(textString);
            spanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(5f), startIndex , textString.length(), 0);// set your font size here

            return spanString;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
int textSize1 = // small size here.
int textSize2 = // large size here.

String text1 = // get your price here
String text2 = "$";

SpannableString span1 = new SpannableString(text1);
span1.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(textSize1), 0, text1.length(), SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

SpannableString span2 = new SpannableString(text2);
span2.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(textSize2), 0, 1, SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

// Join both spans together with a space
CharSequence finalText = TextUtils.concat(span1, " ", span2);
```